# MySql bind parameter is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm having a really annoying problem... I want to update a `div`'s `background-image` with a value from my database. The problem is that the query isn't returning anything. I checked, if the data is sent correctly and it is. Only the query doesn't work.

```
<?php 

include_once '../php/functions.php';
include_once '../php/db_connect.php';

session_start();


$stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1") ;
$stmt3->bind_param('s', $_POST['user1']);
$stmt3->execute();
$stmt3->store_result();
$stmt3->bind_result($user_avatar);
$stmt3->fetch();
echo $user_avatar;
?>
```

and here is the JS:

```
updatepicture('#user1_image' , document.getElementById("user1").innerHTML);
function updatepicture(ussid , uss)
{
var c1='url(\'../images/users/';
var c2='\')';
$.post("../php/get_avatar_game.php",
{
    user1:uss
},
function(data, status)
{
    if( status == 'success' )
    {
    alert(data);
        $(ussid).css("background-image", c1.concat(data,c2));   
    }
    else
    {
        alert( "Proleme la incarcarea imaginii" );
    }   
});
}
```

Comment: check for errors and look at your console

Comment: Are you using an IDE like JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA? If not I'd suggest getting it as it's not only a useful tool but one of the best ones on the market, and you can get a free version. That way you can check the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the first issue here is you should probably be using dbo but I'll give you an answer in the context of mySqli:

Then Now let's look at your myPHPController.php file:

```
//The first issue here is that you don't have an opening PHP tag:
<?php
include_once '../php/functions.php';
include_once '../php/db_connect.php';

//Next issue is you're using Sessions
//Don't use sessions as this makes your program vulnerable
session_start();

//Next add a variable for user1
$user_one = $_POST['user1']

// You do know you're only allowing one record here?
// And double check the name of the table in your database is definitely avatar
$stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1") ; 
$stmt3->bind_param('s', (string)$userOne); //Add the variable
$stmt3->execute();
$stmt3->store_result();
$stmt3->bind_result($user_avatar); // Have you defined $user_avatar
$stmt3->fetch();
echo $user_avatar;
?>
```

This code should compile fine provided you've checked everything I have mentioned

Comment: On another note: if you only have PHP in your file, you don't need to include the closing ?> tag in your file.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I've done what you told me but the query still return nothing, tho the $user_one is correct and the query works on my phpmyadmin

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Because certain methods are deprecated in different versions of PHP and others aren't available in earlier versions.

Comment: @Tituuss10 is your database table column definitely called username and not userName?

Comment: the problems seems to be that $user_one is somehow a diffrent type or variable. Is it because i took it from .innerHTML ?

Comment: when i put the variable it doesn't

Comment: To test your theory, replace `$stmt3->bind_param('s', $userOne);` with `$stmt3->bind_param('s', (string)$userOne);` This will cast the type of the variable to string regardless of what it was before, although if it's taken from .innerHTML it should be a string in the first place

Comment: i can't do that, it says(as an error) that it cannot pass parameter 2